# Why can't we predict turbulence deterministically?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

As far as I've researched, turbulence has a chaotic nature that can't truly be predicted or analyzed. If we took into account all viscous and inertial forces, air resistance, fluid density, etc., why couldn't we predict it?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory

Answer (score 4):

We **can** predict and analyse turbulence, and frequently do. That's one of the things that Computational Fluid Dynamics models do, and what weather forecasting models do, and what climate models do, ... and so on. All of these models have some skill at predicting and analysing turbulence.

What we can't do is predict the exact, specific patterns of turbulence in all circumstances. That's because we currently don't have a bullet-proof method to always get nicely-behaved solutions to the Navier-Stokes equations. Whether such a method can exist or not, is literally [a million-dollar question](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/navier%E2%80%93stokes-equation): that is to say, whoever proves it one way or another stands to win one million US dollars. It's possible that it's a question that will never be solved. You can find [relevant matter on our sister physics site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56496/4066). Whether the underlying system is mathematically chaotic - and thus deterministic - or instead is a stochastic (random) process - is an open question.

But that doesn't prevent us from making useful predictions about turbulence; nor does it prevent us from analysing turbulence. The more information we get about starting conditions, the more skill the models have in prediction.

Answer (score -5):

I think that you've answered your own question. Turbulence is a truly chaotic system at the atomic level, and chaotic systems by definition cannot be predicted.  Minute variations in initial conditions develop into widely different outcomes.

This boils down to the disparity between the Heisenberg and Einstein interpretations of quantum physics.  Whilst there are those that still believe in predestination, the current scientific consensus is that there are natural underlying forces that act totally randomly and can only be described loosely by stochastic means.  This is made even more problematic due to the Observer Effect /Uncertainty Principle at the quantum level where you can't accurately measure some particles without affecting them.  So the more you measure, the more uncertainty is introduced.  If you can't understand how this could be, that's okay because no one else can exactly.  This means that a total quantum model of the convection currents in your coffee cup cannot be constructed.

Comment: Turbulence is best explained by fluctuations at the kolmogorov scale, not the quantum scale.

Comment: Mathematically chaotic systems **are** deterministic.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers You mean like the weather, stock markets and the balls inside the National Lottery machine?  Yet I'm still poor and unexpectedly got wet when I went out..

Comment: Mathematical chaos is **by definition** deterministic, and can be predicted, if all the starting conditions are known to sufficient precision. Whereas "chaotic" in the non-mathematical sense can be either deterministic or stochastic, and can have varying degrees of predictability.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers But the OP is talking of air or water turbulence in the physical world, not a Mandelbrot set in the mathematical one.  This is the Engineering forum, not theoretical mathematics.